# Google Closure Compiler - Dead code removal based on externs

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to use the Google Closure Compiler to split my application code based on where it's going to be run (on the server vs the client) via a single variable. In this example, everything that's going to be called on the server is behind an `isServerSide` var, BUT, the code is being compiled for the client. So I'll set `isServerSide` to false and let the compiler remove everything that wouldn't be run by the client...

Inside of `app.js`:

```
goog.provide('my.app');
my.app.log = function(message) {
  document.write(message);
}
my.app.initClientSide = function() {
  my.app.log('hello client');
}

my.app.initServerSide = function() {
  my.app.log('hello server');
}

if (isServerSide) {
  my.app.log('initing server');
  my.app.initServerSide()
}else my.app.initClientSide();
```

Inside of `externs.js`:

```
/**
 * @define {boolean} is server side?
 */
var isServerSide=false;
```

Command:

```
java -jar bin/compiler.jar --js closure-library/closure/goog/base.js --js app.js --externs externs.js --manage_closure_dependencies true --process_closure_primitives true --summary_detail_level 3 --warning_level VERBOSE --compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --closure_entry_point my.app
```

Expected output:

```
document.write("hello client");
```

Actual output:

```
isServerSide?(document.write("initing server"),document.write("hello server")):document.write("hello client");
```

If I manually type `isServerSide=false;` in `app.js` then I can get it to compile to this:

```
isServerSide=false;document.write("hello client");
```

Which makes me think I'm setting up my `externs.js` wrong (or I just don't understand what externs should actually be used for).

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Externs are for reserving external names and defining function/type signatures (e.g., [jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/contrib/externs/jquery-1.3.2.externs.js?r=66)), so I don't think the compiler pays attention to their values.  Is it possible to split `app.js` into `app_client.js` and `app_server.js` and have the client/server code always call their respective versions?

Comment: As @hyperslug says, externs are to indicate to the compiler that the variable is defined in an outside script.  The compiler **IGNORES ITS VALUE**, assuming that the variable will be set by that outside script.  Therefore, you can see that the compiler does not remove *either* of the two branches in the if-statement, because it does not know what the value of that extern variable is.  What you need is a `@define` within your script, and then use the `--define` compiler switch to turn it on/off.  In this case, you'll get your expected output.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just to confirm, what you both said was absolutely correct :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to add /** @define {boolean} */ isServerSide=false; to each and every script that needs the value of isServerSide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specify @define values by setting them in the compiler call directly.
Externs serve a different purpose like hyperslug correctly states.

You achieve the expected result by putting the @define definition(from your extern) into app.js and then calling the compiler like this:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
--define "isServerSide=false" \
--js closure-library/closure/goog/base.js \
--js app.js \
--manage_closure_dependencies true \
--process_closure_primitives true \
--summary_detail_level 3 \
--warning_level VERBOSE \
--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
--closure_entry_point my.app
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. In case anyone's wondering, I created a new file (`isServerSide.js`) and I `goog.require` that in to `my.app`. That way I don't clutter up app code w/ define statements, but, I can set the `define` in the compiler cmd...